# Fixed filesystem error

Tags: filesystem

I was working on my VM when suddenly I realised all my files have been marked as read-only. I found it strange, so I rebooted, and then I was prompted into "BusyBox". For some unknown reason, **an error has happened in the file system**.

I ran `fcsk` as shown in the picture below. Im theory, it fixed different errors.

As I am not fully aware of what `fcsk` has done, and from my previous experience on Windows fixing its file system, I am now a bit sceptical on whether the file system is really "fixed" or there are corrupted files.

- Can I trust the fixing process?
- Is there a way I can check that all the data is OK without having to open files one by one?
- When an error like the one shown in the picture below happens, what can it be the consequences for the actual data in the drive? Could I expect partial file corruption? full file corruption?

[image: fcsk]

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official *flavors* of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.  *Your paste shows it's Debian which is not Ubuntu*

Comment: I thought it was based on Ubuntu. I will ask in another site, then.

Comment: Debian is *upstream* of Ubuntu, but it's still not Ubuntu.  (based on Ubuntu means *downstream*)

Comment: Yes, I know, thanks.